# Creating a custom attribute that references another and adds a string to the end

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm new to OpenLDAP so please forgive me if my terminology isn't correct.

We have a new SIP phone system in place that uses LDAP for a central phone directory. For incoming calls on handsets connected to the directory, the caller ID shows correctly. For softphones, the caller ID isn't working because the caller is displayed @ (e.g. 02392000000@192.168.1.1).

Can I create a read-only attribute in an existing class that takes another attribute from the same class (e.g. mobilePhone, homePhone) and appends a string to them (e.g. "@192.168.1.1")?

Comment: Yes, but it's non-trivial, and how are you going to maintain it?

Comment: Ah I see, are there no post-update hooks or anything that can update the attribute when others update?